# SwiftMessage: simple way to configure utf8 address encoder

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I'm using SwiftMailer 6.1 (latest at this time) to generate RFC 822 email messages. By default it uses IdnEncoder for email addresses, and this code triggers an error:

```
$message = new Swift_Message();
$message->addTo('straße@germany.de');
echo $message->toString();

// Swift_AddressEncoderException in IdnAddressEncoder.php line 40: Non-ASCII characters not supported in local-part
```

I'm trying to determine the best/recommended/easiest way to configure it.

My best attempt is using the SwiftMailer dependency system to change the behavior, but it looks a bit convoluted/not optimal. Can we do better?

```
$dependencies = Swift_DependencyContainer::getInstance();

$dependencies->register('mime.headerfactory')
    ->asNewInstanceOf('Swift_Mime_SimpleHeaderFactory')
    ->withDependencies([
        'mime.qpheaderencoder',
        'mime.rfc2231encoder',
        'email.validator',
        'properties.charset',
        'address.utf8addressencoder', // default is 'address.idnaddressencoder'
    ]);

$message = new Swift_Message();
$message->addTo('straße@germany.de');
echo $message->toString();
```

Thanks in advance if anyone can help :)